# I am unable to scrape each link content for specific time period from indeed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to python and web scraping. Your help will be appreciated.
I am newbie in programming and practicing . i am using python and selenium for web scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from indeed. goal is to find all jobs posted in last 24 hour and scrape the  external link which is available on job detail page with link text "Apply on company site", Heading, company, name, location, Job description.

i write following code but it is fetching all links on the page correctly and then when i try to open the each link it is only opening first link.
How can i open all links which i fetch one by one. Thanks in advance , here is my code sample:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get("https://indeed.ae/")
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("l")
search.send_keys("Dubai")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    td = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol"))
    )
    divs = td.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")

    for div in divs:
        try:
            title = div.find_element_by_class_name("title")
            anchors = title.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            links = []
            for anchor in anchors:
                link = anchor.get_attribute('href')
                links.append(link)
                print(links)
                for link in links:
                    url = driver.get(link)
        except:
            continue

finally:
    driver.quit()


driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you get the `href`, go to the page, scrape it and say give me the next `href` but now see, you can't find it anymore because you are on a different page.

Solution: Scrape all urls and put them in a list. Iterate the list and one by one go on each of them scrape it and choose next element from that list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running the loop in the wrong place, that's why you're getting only 1 link.

```
try:
        title = div.find_element_by_class_name("title")
        anchors = title.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        links = []
        for anchor in anchors:
            link = anchor.get_attribute('href')
            links.append(link)
        print(links)
        for link in links:
            url = driver.get(link)
```

I don't use selenium, but I am good with web scraping topic. Can please tell me what you're trying to do in the links lists loop ?

```
for link in links:
            url = driver.get(link)
```

Comment: i am fetching all jobs urls and storing in a list, after that i will scrape content of each link separately and store it in excel or json or in list

Comment: you will have to see that how to manage pages in selenium & open each link in different page. check this link - https://www.edureka.co/blog/handle-multiple-windows-in-selenium/