# Can't get data from each of the classes named 'heading' in a page using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi I am new in data scraping. Here I am trying to scrape data from all classes which has the **'heading'** attribute. But in my code it's only printing the first element even though I am using for loop for iterating.

**Expected Output** - Scraping data from all pages classes which has attribute *'heading'*

**Actual Output** - Scraping data only from first element having class name as 'heading' and not even clicking on next button.

The site I am using for testing is [here](https://www.fundoodata.com/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook


DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/Aishwary/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('https://www.fundoodata.com/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida')

# get all classes which has heading as a class name 
company_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('heading')

# to store all companies names from heading class name
names_list = []

while True:

    try:
        for name in company_names: # iterate each name in all div classes named as heading
            text = name.text    # get text data from those elements
            names_list.append(text)
            print(text)
            # Click on next button to get data from next pages as well
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-container"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[44]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a'))))
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[44]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a').click()

    except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
        print("Last page reached")
        break


driver.quit()

# Store those data in excel sheet
df = pd.DataFrame(names_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('companies_names.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='List')
writer.save()
```

Comment: @VisheshMangla I really wanted to select something like classname or id of next button but unfortunately it contains only href tag and text saying 'next'.

Comment: I see I misunderstood something, sorry.

Comment: This may be happening here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911746/i-am-unable-to-scrape-each-link-content-for-specific-time-period-from-indeed/62911978#62911978

Comment: @VisheshMangla Thank you so much this is also helpful. Now I'm able to scrap using both ways BS4 and Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will get all business names from the page:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.fundoodata.com/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida'

all_data = []
while True:
    print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )
    for h in soup.select('div.heading'):
        all_data.append({'Name' : h.text})
        print(h.text)

    next_page = soup.select_one('a:contains("Next")')
    if not next_page:
        break

    url = 'https://www.fundoodata.com' + next_page['href']

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
                              Name
0                   BirlaSoft Ltd
1             HCL Infosystems Ltd
2            HCL Technologies Ltd
3           NIIT Technologies Ltd
4          3Pillar Global Pvt Ltd
..                             ...
481  Innovaccer Analytics Pvt Ltd
482         Kratikal Tech Pvt Ltd
483          Sofocle Technologies
484    SquadRun Solutions Pvt Ltd
485   Zaptas Technologies Pvt Ltd

[486 rows x 1 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you for your effort. You didn't only help me to get data instead you taught me that we can perform such scrapping by just BeautifulSoup without any need of selenium. I appreciate it.